# Cannot Bypass Signature Check in Firefox Developer Edition 75

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, signing, add-on

I'm trying to install my extension without getting it signed. I tried following steps:

1. install Firefox developer edition 75
2. Set `xpinstall.signatures.required` to false
3. Restart the Firefox
4. Delete META-INF directory from the extension zip file

But when I try to install the extension in the add-ons manager I get

```
The add-on downloaded from this site could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt.
```

In the browser console I get

```
 1585752245599  addons.xpi  WARN    Invalid XPI: Error: Cannot find id for addon C:\the.zip(resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIInstall.jsm:1532:19) JS Stack trace: loadManifest@XPIInstall.jsm:1532:19
async*init@XPIInstall.jsm:2040:18
createLocalInstall@XPIInstall.jsm:2989:20
getInstallForFile@XPIInstall.jsm:4172:25
XPIProvider[meth]@XPIProvider.jsm:3138:28
promiseCallProvider@AddonManager.jsm:238:31
getInstallForFile/<@AddonManager.jsm:1870:29
getInstallForFile@AddonManager.jsm:1883:7
getInstallForFile@AddonManager.jsm:4003:33
installAddonsFromFilePicker/</<@aboutaddonsCommon.js:238:42
```

Add on can be temporarily installed successfully in the `about:debugging`

Answer (score 0):

The option `xpinstall.signatures.required` works for me on Firefox Developer Edition 76. The error message you saw is different from the one for a signature check failure. Did you repack files with a directory like following?:

```
+ zipfile.xpi
  + [folder]
    + manifest.json
    + background.js
    + ...
```

Then you need to repack files without the folder and put files under the archive file directly like:

```
+ zipfile.xpi
  + manifest.json
  + background.js
  + ...
```